# Using AWS::Region in Policy Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to dynamically change the s3 resource name based on current cloud formation stack region. Cloudformation stack updates without any error. 
Am I doing something wrong? I am expecting to have a policy with {AWS::Region} resolved to us-east-1.

```
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Sid: RestrictS3Access
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:GetObject'
            Resource:
              - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-${AWS::Region}test/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
              - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-${AWS::Region}test/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
```

I am expecting to see the policy as follows. I am checking results from aws console.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-us-east-1/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-us-east-1/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "RestrictS3Access"
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the behavior you are seeing, and how does that compare to your expectations?

Comment: Thanks @JasonWadsworth. I updated the question with the expected result.

Comment: @DineshNS could still do with a bit more info here. What is the outcome of you updating your stack with that YAML?

Comment: I can see as follows.
"Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
Only one line in the policy as well.
If i remove {AWS::Region} i can see both.

Comment: @DineshNS I'd suggest updating your question with the *full* JSON policy that's been created. We can then help you determine why it's different to what you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I will try to create separate yaml for this case. this is a part of huge yaml and I can't share it as well. 

The way I am using Sub in the Resource correct?

Comment: @DineshNS no need to provide any more YAML. What I'm looking for is the full JSON policy that was created when you updated your template in Cloudformation. Or are you saying that no policy was created at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` to remain unchanged, you need to escape it with `${!}`.

```
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
      - Sid: RestrictS3Access
        Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - 's3:GetObject'
        Resource:
          - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-${AWS::Region}test/${!cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
          - !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::dnsa-${AWS::Region}test/${!cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
```